# Spring Data Neo4j: Complex relationships not persisting

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

When adding multiple relationships between nodes simultaneously, only some of them are created. In the example below, the calls to `makeUser(...)` are only populating some of the relationships.

**Main**

```
@Transactional
void clearDatabase() {
    session.execute("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r");
}

void createPeople() {

    Person mark = new Person("Mark");
    mark.password = "mark123";
    people.save(mark);

    Organisation noxRentals = new Organisation("Nox Rentals");
    organisations.save(noxRentals);

    makeUser(noxRentals, mark, "Administrator", Right.ADMINISTRATE);
    makeUser(noxRentals, richard, "Administrator", Right.ADMINISTRATE);
    makeUser(classicVillas, mark, "Administrator", Right.ADMINISTRATE);
    makeUser(classicVillas, richard, "Administrator", Right.ADMINISTRATE);
    makeUser(classicVillas, charlotte, "Reservations", Right.LOGIN, Right.SEND_QUOTES);

}

@Transactional
void makeUser (Organisation organisation, Person person, String role, Right...rights) {
    IsUser account = organisation.addUser(person, role);
    account.addRights(rights);
    organisations.save(organisation);
}

void run() {
    clearDatabase();
    createPeople();
}
```

**Resulting in (notice Nox has no relationships):**

[image: Missing Relationships]

**Organisation.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Organisation extends NitroBaseEntity {

    @Relationship(type = "IsUser", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    Set<IsUser> users = new HashSet<>();

    public IsUser addUser(Person person, String role) {
        IsUser user = new IsUser(person, this, role);
        this.users.add(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person extends NitroBaseEntity {

    @Property
    String password;

    @Relationship(type = "IsUser", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    Set<IsUser> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<IsUser> getUserAccounts() {
        return this.users;
    }

}
```

**IsUser.java**

```
@RelationshipEntity
public class IsUser {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @StartNode
    public Person person;

    @EndNode
    public Organisation organisation;

    @Property
    public String role;

    @Property
    public Set<Right> rights = new HashSet<>();

    public IsUser (Person person, Organisation organisation, String role) {
        this.person = person;
        this.organisation = organisation;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Complete source code: https://bitbucket.org/sparkyspider/neo4j-sandbox-4/src/22eb3aba82e33dfe473ee15e26f9b4701c62fd8e/src/main/java/com/noxgroup/nitro/config/DatabaseInitializer.java?at=master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things missing-

1. The type has to be specified on the `@RelationshipEntity` as well, like this `@RelationshipEntity(type = "IsUser")`
2. In `Organisation.addUser()`, add the IsUser to the Person too, something like `person.users.add(user);`. The entities have to be navigable from both ends.

Comment: Can you perhaps rather make this throw an error than behave strangely :)